# Orphan deletion in Hibernate (when have multiple mapped objects)

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got this structure of project:

```
class UserServiceSettingsImpl {
...

    @ManyToOne
    private UserImpl user;

    @ManyToOne
    private ServiceImpl service;
...

}

class ServiceImpl {
....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "service", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserServiceSettingsImpl> userServiceSettings;
....

}

class UserImpl {
....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<UserServiceSettingsImpl> serviceSettings;
....
}
```

I am trying to delete Service and everything that belongs to it (UserServiceSettingsImpl), but accidentally, this settings are not being removed (I suppose because they are not orphans since UserImpl has them too). So the thing is: is there a way to delete Settings, without deleting them from user manually (there could be a lot of users with a lot of settings, iterating through it could take a lot of time) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in why the UserServiceSettings are not being deleted when deleting a service if they are also referenced by a User.  They are not orphans and will have to be deleted explicitly per your business logic.

Three ideas:

1. **Use the ORM to batch delete entities.**
   It's not much different than iterating, but might be optimized while still using the ORM.

   `List settingsCopy = new ArrayList<>(service.getSettings());
   service.getSettings().clear();
   myDao.deleteAll(settingsCopy);`
2. **Use direct HSQL/SQL to batch delete.**
   This depends on what framework you are using, but generally would be something like this,  probably in your repository/dao class:
   `delete from UserServiceSettingsImpl o where o.service.id = ?` 
    However, hibernate does not support JOINs when deleting, afaik, so this doesn't work as written. It's generally necessary to rework the HSQL to use a "delete where id IN(...)" type format.
3. **Setup `CASCADE DELETE`s and `CASCADE UPDATE`s in your database DDL**, outside of the ORM framework. (Not recommended.)

*However*, the last two options have problems if there is chance that service's and user's UserServiceSettings can be modified at same time via multiple threads (even with correct transaction boundaries), or if those entities will be used within the orm context after the delete without a reload.  In that case, you will likely run in to unexpected and sporadic errors with the last two approaches, and instead, should iterate the settings and delete via the ORM, even if it is inefficient.

Even with the first approach, it can be tricky to avoid errors in highly concurrent environments when deleting shared entities.

Comment: What is myDao? Is it DAO for Settings? And is deleteAll a simple remove() every object?

Comment: The myDao could be anything, but generally is the dao you use for handling data operations on UserServiceSettings. Its depends on framework you are using as to what deleteAll might look like. If using straight Hibernate, then yes, I think a deleteAll implementation would have to be a straight iteration of every object with a delete call, per @Hedley's answer.  If using Spring, there's `getHibernateTemplate().deleteAll(list)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that you cannot delete them in any kind of automatic way - they will never be orphans. I think the best you can do is just write yourself a helper method. e.g. if you have a ServiceDao class, you would just add a helper as:

```
public void deleteServiceAndSettings(Service service) {
    for (UserServiceSettings setting : service.getUserServiceSettings()) {
        session.delete(setting);
    }
    session.delete(service);
}
```